# Нужно ли явно откатывать транзацию в случает ошибки?

Tags: c#, sql

Например, есть такой код:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection())
{
    conn.Open()
    var tran = conn.BeginTransaction();
    //Какие-то запросы
    tran.Commit()
}
```

Обязательно ли перехватывать все возможные ошибки, а потом выполнять явный `Rollback`?

Я могу ошибаться, но, вроде, в случае ошибки соединение должно умереть и после этого сам MS SQL Server должен выполнить откат.

Comment: Может оно так и будет, но только когда это случится? И что делать другим транзакциям, ждать, пока первая сама отвалится?

Comment: Если есть основание для отката транзакции - она должна быть откачена 1) немедленно; 2) явно. *в случае ошибки соединение должно умереть* В случае ошибки соединения - скорее да, чем нет (хотя зависит от ошибки и настроек соединения), иначе скорее нет, чем да.